# is it possible to install all types using pnpm

Tags: typescript, pnpm

I have removed the project `node_modules`, now most of the package shows error:

```
Cannot find module 'react-redux' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

is it possible to install types of all package that the current project needed? I do not want to install types package one by one. I have tried this command but did not work:

```
> pnpm install --save-dev '@types/*'
 ERR_PNPM_FETCH_404  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2F*: Not Found - 404

This error happened while installing a direct dependency of /Users/john/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web

@types/* is not in the npm registry, or you have no permission to fetch it.

An authorization header was used: Bearer npm_[hidden]
Progress: resolved 30, reused 30, downloaded 0, added 0
```

Comment: Don't do this, the amount of `@types` is very large and will cause your project very slow at build time

Comment: is it possible to install the types that the current project needed, not all of the types.

Comment: not sure how do do this in `pnpm`. I use `yarn` as the manager and it has a [plugin](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/tree/master/packages/plugin-typescript) that automatically install corresponding `@types` (but only when add new package)

Answer (score 1):

You can run [typesync](https://github.com/jeffijoe/typesync) in your `preinstall` script:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "typesync || :"
  }
}
```

It's not perfect, but it helps you notice when you forget to add a `@types/` package.